# MeteorJS: Sort a collection by date

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have an app that consumes an XML data feed. In this XML data there is an attribute of dateacquired.

An entry into the collection looks like this:

```
{
  "_id": "22uYws2ki9qqALSwA",
  "lat": "",
  "lng": "",
  "title": "FT Content Writer (MUST have exp in Marketo)",
  "url": "http://my.jobs/bfb2464b0c1246698eb4b8f251f50658321",
  "company": "Robert Half The Creative Group",
  "address": "Norcross, GA",
  "dateacquired": "2014-3-10 10:07 AM",
  "onet": null,
  "jvid": "bfb2464b0c1246698eb4b8f251f50658321"
}
```

I am pulling a collection like `Jobs.find({})`

How can I sort by the dateacquired attribute?

Comment: Did you try `Jobs.find({}).sort({dateacquired:1})`?  I don't know meteor but this is how it's done in mongo query.  If you want to sort by descending, use -1 instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass [certain query modifiers](http://docs.meteor.com/#find) as the second argument to `find`. `sort` is one of them:

```
Jobs.find({}, { sort: { dateacquired: 1 } });
```